# dijkstra and costEvaluator - interpretation

Tags: neo4j

I have some nodes and links (relationships) between nodes.

By default dijkstra (in neo4j) takes into account cost property of relationships to find shortest path between nodes.

I want also to take into account cost property of nodes, so I defined the following `costEvaluator`:

```
CostEvaluator<Double> costEvaluator = new CostEvaluator<Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double getCost(Relationship relationship, Direction direction) {
                Long costR = (Long) relationship.getProperty("cost");
                Long costE = (Long) relationship.getEndNode().getProperty("cost");
                Long cost = costR + costE; 
                return cost.doubleValue();
            }
        };
```

I used it in the following code:

```
    PathFinder<WeightedPath> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(
            Traversal.expanderForTypes(ROAD, Direction.BOTH), 
            costEvaluator);

    WeightedPath path = finder.findSinglePath(node1, node2);

    System.out.println("Path weight: " + path.weight());
    for (Node n: path.nodes()) {
        System.out.println("Node: " + n.getId() + "-" +  n.getProperty("cost"));
    }
    for (Relationship r: path.relationships()) {
        System.out.println("Relationship: " + r.getId() + "-" + r.getProperty("cost") );
    }
```

When I execute this code I have following results:

```
Path weight: 1395.0
Node: 106-100
Node: 29-30
Node: 85-30
Node: 16-40
Node: 10-100
Node: 152-60
Relationship: 344-334
Relationship: 13-398
Relationship: 406-38
Relationship: 326-146
Relationship: 500-289
```

Why Path weight is 1395? It should be 1465 (in my opinion).

Cost of the relationships: 334 + 398 + 38 + 146 + 289 = 1205

Cost of the end nodes of these relationships: 30 + 30 + 40 + 100 + 60 = 260

1205+260=1465

Why Path weight is 1395?

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Could you also output the node-id and cost of each relationship's end-node? I think in your cost-calculation you have to take the direction into account (to determine which is the end-node you're currently looking at) `rel.getEndNode` is for `Direction.OUTGOING` otherwise it is the `rel.getStartNode`

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thanks a lot.
End node - is of course the end node in accordance with the original direction of the relationship, and not the end node in the "direction" of the shortests path.

Comment: Relationships which belong to the shortest path are as follows: (106-100)--[344-334]-->(29-30)
(29-30)--[13-398]-->(85-30)
(85-30)<--[406-38]--(16-40)
(16-40)<--[326-146]--(10-100)
(10-100)--[500-289]-->(152-60) - so Path weight must be 1395. Thanks again.